# MySQL filters col of a list of separated items within a range

Tags: mysql

I want to filter items in a table which contain a column with concatenated integers in this way:

```
3|7|2|10|11
```

I want to get only results that contain a specific range like:

```
[0 - 10] return result for 3|7|2|10|9
[0 - 10] don't return result for 13|7|2|10|9
```

The length of separated items is not defined.

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Juergen D. is absolutely right: you are handcuffing the database by introducing this problem in the first place with multiple values in a single column.

That said, I want to help in the short-term in addition to simply lecturing. :) So here we go.

---

We're going to make use of the excellent [user-defined SPLIT_STR() function by Luis Rodriguez](http://injustfiveminutes.com/2012/10/17/split-function-in-mysql/), which is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Now, I've written another function that will iterate through the delimited values of each string in your table, calling `SPLIT_STR()` along the way, and check each value to see if it falls below the specified minimum (`0` in your example) or above the maximum (`10` in your example):

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_vals (
  x varchar(255),
  delim varchar(12),
  mini int,
  maxi int
)
RETURNS bool
BEGIN
  declare len, pos int;
  declare val int;
  set len = length(x) - length(replace(x,'|',''));
  set pos = 1;
  WHILE pos <= len DO
    set val = split_str(x, delim, pos);
    IF val < mini or val > maxi THEN
      return false;
    END IF;
    set pos = pos + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN true;
END //
```

Let me break it down a bit for you. You pass in the delimited string in question (`x`), the delimiter (`|`), the minimum allowed value (`mini`), and the maximum allowed value (`maxi`).

```
set len = length(x) - length(replace(x,'|',''));
```

This gets the total number of tokens, or delimited values, in the given string `x`. This tells our while-loop how many times to circle around.

```
set val = split_str(x, delim, pos);
```

This gets the actual value of each token (in your example: 3, 7, 2, 10, 9, for the first record).

```
IF val < mini or val > maxi THEN
  return false;
END IF;
```

If the given value is below the minimum or above the maximum allowable, we exit the function and return FALSE.

```
END WHILE;
RETURN true;
```

If we get to `RETURN true` that means each value passed the test, and the record overall fits your criteria.

---

So for your example of checking with minimum of 0 and maximum of 10, you would call something like:

```
select str, check_vals(str,'|',0,10) `result` from t;
```

which would get you

```
|         str | result |
|-------------|--------|
|  3|7|2|10|9 |   true |
| 13|7|2|10|9 |  false |
```

Comment: Great post ... Thanks for all! At the end I separated my values in a new table ...